# Python: Pickle.Unpicklingerror when trying to load model weights received as UDP packages

Tags: python, sockets, socket.io, udp, pickle

I want to run an experiment that involves multicasting in a network. For that, I have a server which sends some processed model weights (Tuple of ndarrays) back to the client. When trying to serialize and deserialize the received weights using pickle.save() and pickle.load(), I always get the following error _pickle.UnpicklingError : invalid load key, 'XXX' with XXX being some key inside the dump.

i am using python 3.10

Minimal reproducible example below

transmitter:

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct
import sys
import numpy as np

group_ip_address = "239.0.0.100"
port = 10000
source_ip = "192.168.68.116"
source_port = 12345

print("Multicast sender transmitting data to ", group_ip_address, "/", port, ". Local address: ", source_ip,
      "/", source_port)

message = tuple(np.random.rand(*(100,100)) for _ in range(10))

multicast_group = (group_ip_address, port)

# Create UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# bind to selected address
sock.bind((source_ip, source_port))

# Set the time-to-live for messages to 1 so they do not go past the
# local network segment.
ttl = struct.pack('b', 1)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)

try:
    BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

    # Send data to the multicast group
    print(sys.getsizeof(message))
    print(message)
    serialized = pickle.dumps(message)
    for i in range(0, len(serialized), BUFFER_SIZE):
        data = serialized[i:i + BUFFER_SIZE]
        sock.sendto(data, multicast_group)

        while True:
            sock.settimeout(1)
            print('waiting to receive acknowledgment')
            try:

                data, server = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
            except socket.timeout:
                print('timed out, resending package')
                sock.sendto(data, multicast_group)
            else:
                print('received "%s" from %s' % (data, server))
                break
    # tell edge server to stop the recv loop
    sock.sendto(b'END', multicast_group)



finally:
    print('closing socket')
    sock.close()
```

receiver

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct


multicast_group = '239.0.0.100'
port = 10000

print("Multicast receiver listening for data at ", multicast_group, "/", port)
############

server_address = ('', port)

# Create UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind to the server address
sock.bind(server_address)

# Tell the operating system to add the socket to the multicast group
# on all interfaces.
group = socket.inet_aton(multicast_group)
mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
packets = []
while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print(data)
    if not data or data.endswith(b'END'):
        break
    packets.append(data)
    sock.sendto(b'ack', address)
    # print('received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
    # print('total : %s' % len(packets))

bytes = b''.join(packets)
new_aggregated_parameters = pickle.loads(bytes)
print(type(new_aggregated_parameters))
```

Comment: The code provided works for me.  I get no error and receive the original random array sent.   Only changed `source_ip` to `''` (empty string).  What hardware are you using?  I'm running both scripts on the same system.

Comment: Note in the transmitter the `bind` (and hence the `source_ip` and `source_port`) are not required.

Comment: I'm using a single machine running two VMs. Each script is running in a separate VM